# Shipping Business Logic from Server?

Tags: flutter, dart, backend

I have a UI form in my Flutter App as input for some business logic in my app. Currently, this logic is implemented inside the app but I need to make it easily updateable, meaning I would like to have this logic on my backend. The usual method would be sending the input to my backend and returning the resulting data. However, I render a preview of the result in my form, so for every input change (such as checking a checkbox) I would need to make a new request, meaning it would buffer before showing the preview.

It would be great if I somehow could serve my business logic to the app. Something like sending a dart function only once where this function gets executed every time when an input changes. Is there a method to do something like this?